# Python regex: avoid to match first occurrence only

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the current test text:

> "but two of them were fool saying twenty six nine seven twenty six then the
> seven thousand twenty three people and all the people saying is three
> two just one person said one thousand thirty three and three and two
> and seven three "

I would like to match the numbers as they should be so `two, twenty six, nine, seven, twenty six, seven thousand twenty three etc.`

I am actually playing with this regex:

`r"\b(one|two|three|seven|\stwenty\ssix|\sseven\sthousand|\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree|\sone\sthousand\sthirty\sthree)\b"`

however, when I run `re.findall(REGEX, text)` I can't get `seven thousand twenty three` but I just have `two, twenty six, seven, twenty six, seven thousand, three` - so seven thousand is found but the right answer should be `seven thousand twenty three`.

EDIT:

I know that in my regex there's `seven thousand` and `seven thousand twenty three`. What I would like `re` is to match with respect to the next words as well, so it could capture `seven thousand twenty three` and not just stopping at `seven thousand`

Is there a way to get `seven thousand twenty three` as a whole?

Comment: You have an extra split for `seven thousand` in your `REGEX`. It should be `r"\b(one|two|three|seven|\stwenty\ssix|\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree|\sone\sthousand\sthirty\sthree)\b"`. Right?

Comment: nope that's a test I am doing, 
In my regex I have both `seven thousand` and `seven thousand twenty three`. What I would like `re` to achieve is to not stop at the first matching but checking the next 2/3 words to get to `seven thousand twenty three`

Comment: @SM1312 thanks for your suggestion. I updated the question to make it clearer, as it was a bit confused :)

Comment: Try changing the order. Keep your `seven thousand twenty three` before `seven thousand` in your regex. `REGEX = r"\b(one|two|three|seven|\stwenty\ssix|\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree|\sseven\sthousand|\sone\sthousand\sthirty\sthree)\b"`. @Stefano

Comment: You can put the most specific match first in the alternation, see https://regex101.com/r/i7O3qG/1

Comment: If `seven thousand twenty three` is not present do you want to get `seven thousand` ? If so you have to get both of them and only use the 2nd if the 1st is not present.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the regex from the ["Regex to Match Numbers in Plain English"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-numbers-in-english.html) Rexegg.com page.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iERSrm):

```py
import re

one_to_9 = r"(?:f(?:ive|our)|s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hree|wo)|(?:ni|o)ne|eight)" # end one_to_9 definition
ten_to_19 = r"(?:(?:(?:s(?:even|ix)|f(?:our|if)|nine)te|e(?:ighte|lev))en|t(?:(?:hirte)?en|welve))" # end ten_to_19 definition
two_digit_prefix = r"(?:(?:s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hir|wen)|f(?:if|or)|eigh|nine)ty)" # end two_digit_prefix definition
one_to_99 = fr"(?:{two_digit_prefix}(?:[-\s]{one_to_9})?|{ten_to_19}|{one_to_9})" # end one_to_99 definition
one_to_999 = fr"(?:{one_to_9}\shundred(?:\s(?:and\s)?{one_to_99})?|{one_to_99})" # end one_to_999 definition
one_to_999_999 = fr"(?:{one_to_999}\sthousand(?:\s{one_to_999})?|{one_to_999})" # end one_to_999_999 definition
one_to_999_999_999 = fr"(?:{one_to_999}\smillion(?:\s{one_to_999_999})?|{one_to_999_999})" # end one_to_999_999_999 definition
one_to_999_999_999_999 = fr"(?:{one_to_999}\sbillion(?:\s{one_to_999_999_999})?|{one_to_999_999_999})" # end one_to_999_999_999_999 definition
one_to_999_999_999_999_999 = fr"(?:{one_to_999}\strillion(?:\s{one_to_999_999_999_999})?|{one_to_999_999_999_999})" # end one_to_999_999_999_999_999 definition
bignumber = fr"(?:zero|{one_to_999_999_999_999_999})" # end bignumber definition
zero_to_9 = fr"(?:{one_to_9}|zero)" # end zero to 9 definition
decimals = fr"point(?:\s{zero_to_9})+" # end decimals definition
numeral_pattern = fr"{bignumber}(?:\s{decimals})?"

rx = re.compile(numeral_pattern)
text = "but two of them were fool saying twenty six nine seven twenty six then the seven thousand twenty three people and all the people saying is three two just one person said one thousand thirty three and three and two and seven three"
print(rx.findall(text))
```

Output:

```
['two', 'twenty six', 'nine', 'seven', 'twenty six', 'seven thousand twenty three', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'one thousand thirty three', 'three', 'two', 'seven', 'three']
```

Comment: Is this from one of your utility files or something? :p

Comment: @oda No, just converted the code today

Comment: Ah okay. Seems pretty useful to have. Up-voted! HAGD!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your regex. You must swap **\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree** with **\sseven\sthousand**.

As below a correct regex will get **seven thousand twenty three**

```
\b(one|two|three|seven|\stwenty\ssix|\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree|\sseven\sthousand|\sone\sthousand\sthirty\sthree)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4wM85l/1)

```
import re

regex = r"\b(one|two|three|seven|\stwenty\ssix|\sseven\sthousand\stwenty\sthree|\sseven\sthousand|\sone\sthousand\sthirty\sthree)\b"

test_str = "\"but two of them were fool saying twenty six nine seven twenty six then the seven thousand twenty three people and all the people saying is three two just one person said one thousand thirty three and three and two and seven three \""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```